# gsub replacement not working when trying to remove repeated characters

Tags: r, gsub

I'm having problems with the gsub function. I need to remove repeated characters, but the replacement I'm using is not working:

```
x <- 'loveeee'

gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\{2,}', '\\1', x)
```

For all the characters which are repeated more than twice I want them to be reduced. In the example above, I'd like the result to be 'lovee'.

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen if you have `eeeeeeeeee`.  Do you just want two of the `e`s to survive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems: (1) you have a stray `\\` before the `{2,}` and (2) [[:alpha:]] will match any sequence of letters, not only a sequence of identical letters.  Here is a way of doing what I believe you want, usingthe back-reference `\1` to say "more letters like the first one":

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1{2,}', '\\1\\1', x)
```

Comment: why does the the character class need to be nested in another character class

Comment: @rawr, I believe `[:alpha:]` is the equivalent `a-zA-Z`, and thus `[[:alpha:]]` is the equivalent of the required `[a-zA-Z]`.  This allows you to use the predefined sets as building blocks of more complex character classes like `[[:digit:]a-f]` (which is equivalent to `[0-9a-f]`).